# Is listener of onClick destroyed when button is destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am instantiating many buttons that when clicked need to call a function (via listener). But I'm also very often destroying them. Are these listeners then also destroyed or do I need to delete them otherwise?

Example:

```
public void makeButton()
{
    GameObject spawnedButton = Instantiate(prefabButton, prefabButton.transform.position, prefabButton.transform.rotation) as GameObject;   

    spawnedButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(()=>
    {
        listedButtonClicked(someOtherObjectThatWillNotBeDeleted, spawnedButton);
    });
}

public void listedButtonClicked(GameObject target, GameObject button)
{
    Debug.Log(target);
    Debug.Log(button);
}
```

...so when `spawnedButton` is destroyed, will this listener remain? I'm instantiating and deleting a huge amount of buttons so it could be relevant for me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when saying "_listener_"? The lambda expression (`() => { ... }`; i.e., anonymous method), or the `listedButtonClicked` method, or the object providing the _listedButtonClicked_ method?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm referring to. If I accumulate 100,000s of buttons over time (only maybe 100 existing in reality), could this represent a problem? If these don't work when button is destroyed then it's all right, that's how my thinking goes at least.

Comment: If the button object is destroyed then also the `Button` component is. So `onClick` will never be called anymore.

Comment: According to the post/answer at https://answers.unity.com/questions/1070242/why-ui-event-handlers-dont-get-memory-leaks-if-lis.html (which Vanetrhane copied in whole below), it seems that when not calling _RemoveListener_, the event handler (and its associated object; in this case the anonymous method) will stay in memory (i.e., leak). :(

Comment: Just to summarize, answer is from 3 years ago, so it needs to be confirmed as versions have changed. The OP is other way around, the Button is removed, not the script holding the method. Cleaning the onClick is best practice so there is no wonder about if and why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok this is going to get a bit deep.

Consider this:

```
Button button;
void Start()
{
     button.onClick.AddListener(Method);
}
void Method()
{
    print("Hey");
}
```

This goes just fine, your Button component gets a "link" to Method so when the onClick is triggered, it jumps to the address of Method and runs the code from there.

Second scenario:

```
Button button;
void Start()
{
     button.onClick.AddListener(Method);
     Destroy(this);
}
void Method()
{
    print("Hey");
}
```

Notice I destroy the currentcomponent, run this and trigger the onClick and no issue(??!!), it prints fine.

Third scenario:

```
Button button;
string str = "Hey there";
void Start()
{
     button.onClick.AddListener(Method);
     Destroy(this);
}
void Method()
{
    print(this.str);
}
```

It crashes. And now for the explanation. A method is ALWAYS static, the compiler (or the creators) is smart enough to consider that there is no need for each instance to have their own method but instead to have a shared method template to which the instance can pass itself.

Methods are as such:

```
  void ClassName.MethodName(this ClassName);
```

The this parameter is moved to the front when using instance call and is made non-compulsory. That this parameter is actually available within the method as you can use it. Again, it is not compulsory.

So, in the first case, it works though the Script did not exist anymore, this is because there was no usage of any instance member. In the last example, str is used and since the object is no longer, it throws null reference exception.

**Considering the other way around.**

If the creating script remains and the Button game object or component is being destroyed, then you have no risk at all. It would be wiser to clear the onClick event but since it will be destroyed, other way around. Your spawner loses any knowledge of the Button at the next iteration of the loop that is creating all the button:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    GameObject go = null; // new reference added on method stack
    go = Instantiate<GameObject>(btnPrefab); // new instance added to reference
} // go connection is lost right here, a new go added to stack in next iteration
```

Comment: So it is better to call RemoveListener to clear the onClick handler?

Comment: I dont think there is any other way. I believe the -= operator is not usable since UnityEvent is not of type event nor delegate. Just a wrapper object gor a list of delegate. So RemoveListener is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I found your answer [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1070242/why-ui-event-handlers-dont-get-memory-leaks-if-lis.html) to be more precise

I could be misunderstanding the wording of the docs but AddListener is meant to add a non.persistent listener.

But, the following shows a weird behaviour (at least until I get it explained):

```
 private float myFloat = 10f;
 [SerializeField] private Button button = null;
 void Start( )
 {
     button.onClick.AddListener(MyMethod);
     DestroyImmediate(this.gameObject);
 }
 public void MyMethod()
 {
     Debug.Log("Call " + this.myFloat);
     this.myFloat ++;
 }
```

the best part being that the object is surely gone, the this.myFloat still gets printed AND increased, and I don't have any persistent listener.

If I remove in Destroy then all goes fine. It seems the AddListener is creating a link to the object in memory and even triggering the GC will not collect the object. Using a weak reference would probably bring it back to life I am thinking.

What is even better is that if I create a reference to my script above and call for the myFloat value, I get it??!! Despite the inspector showing Missing(Type)??!!...

This tells me that we have here a memory leak if the programmer is not removing the listener manually, until I am proven wrong. obviously.

so.... yes and no. According to documentation it is destroyed, the inspector says its destroyed, but it is still in memory... and can be called.

*edit* there is a RemoveListener()method but it seems to do nothing but slow everything down, and i've seen it throw some strange errors. unless your really worried about performance, expect unity to do its best at removing them onDestroy() and don't worry about it to much...

Comment: Can you tell me how you click on a button that is not present in the scene anymore?

Comment: @derHugo The question is is not about whether the listener (event handler) is being invoked or not, it is about whether the reference to the listener disappears ("the listener is destroyed") or not when the button is being destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, this entire thing is somewhat esoteric to me. I'm basically worried about "listeners" somehow "listening" in the script while their target objects (buttons) are destroyed, so decreasing performance after accumulating thousands of them. But maybe I have it wrong.

Comment: Well he said `the best part being that the object is surely gone, the this.myFloat still gets printed AND increased` I just wondered how he calls it. Note that `DestroyImmediate` should only be used for editor scripting and is not even available in a build. Maybe this is where the strange behavior comes from?

Comment: @MrQuestions, it probably is not so much an issue with regard to performance but about memory leaks (remember, a delegate -- and a listener is just a delegate) also holds a reference to the object that contains the method the delegate refers to. So, if the listener delegate is not removed from the event and is staying somewhere in an Unity-internal data-structure after destroying the button, then the object associated with that delegate will never be garbage-collected. Which could lead to a memory leak. I am not 101% sure about whether Unity is really doing that, but better safe than sorry

Comment: @derHugo, ah okay. I am not sure how Unity works, but that could indeed be some "abuse" of some function, or perhaps just be some artifact of multi-threaded behavior inside of Unity...

Comment: absolutely bad style! tut tut! my bad. i did intend to lead with a link

Comment: I removed my previous comment as off-topic I realized. On the other hand, the given answer is from 3 years ago, and i think the behaviours have changed since I have experienced what I explain in the other answer.

Comment: Removed my comment as well. Also removed my comment with regard to not crediting the source, as Vanethrane obviously does now :)

Comment: All in all, it should be emphasized that cleaning the onClick is important.

Comment: Everts got an upvote from me for his very in depth answer... which explains why the listener can still be called when technically it has been destroyed. very thorough.

Comment: Take what I say with a bit of salt 'cos my coding skills are not great. All this is probably additionally influenced and by the double nature of the Unity objects (at least the objects inheriting from UnityEngine.Object). BTW DestroyImmediate() is related to that dual nature. When an object is destroyed it is destroyed on the engine side (c++) but remains on the user space side until GC takes care of it (Unity just makes some magic to pretend it doesn't exist). In short, as others already said, it is a good practice to remove listeners OnDestroy/OnDisable to avoid "memory leaks".

Comment: @Everts what do you mean "cleaning"? Using RemoveListener?